# SSH connection closed/dropped a few seconds after successful login

Tags: ssh, jenkins

I have been using a linux instance, as my deploy server and I am connecting my deploy server via Jump server. I used to deploy the artifact from Jenkins. The Deploy will take approx 2 mins to complete. Now, all of a sudden, I am getting kicked off from the server every time I am connecting from Jenkins.

The amount of time I can remain connected varies, but generally seems to be on the range of 1-30 seconds. All settings are the same as they were when things were working smoothly. The problem has persisted for over a week at this point. Nothing else seems to be out of the ordinary on Jenkins master, my deploy server and jump server. While connected, I have full access to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article is quite the same like your
You may check it out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/349631/why-is-my-ssh-connection-dropping-immediately-after-i-enter-my-password

Comment: Yeah, I have already seen the page. My problem is slightly different that I am able to connect manually from Jump server and the SSH connection is alive until I closed.

But when I connect from Jenkins via Jump server the SSH connection getting closed automatically within 30 seconds.